# I want to multiply a 3x3xn by a 3x1xn and get a 3x1xn

Tags: python, pytorch

I do matrixial multiplication in a pytorch model. As a 3x3 matrix by a 3x1 vector is equal to a 3x1 vector, I want my 3x3xn * 3x1xn to be equal to a 3x1xn, with n my bash size. But unfortunately, I get a 3x3xn with `mul` and an error with `matmul`.

```bash
import torch

T = torch.zeros(3,1,125)
R = torch.zeros(3,3,125)

out = torch.matmul(R,T)
print(out.size())
```

expected output:

```bash
torch.Size([3, 1, 125])
```

Output get:

```bash
RuntimeError: Expected size for first two dimensions of batch2 tensor to be: [3, 125] but got: [3, 1].
```

Comment: `mul` is element-wise multiplication. For matrix multiplication, look at `matmul`: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html

Comment: I've already tried but it's not working: RuntimeError: Expected size for first two dimensions of batch2 tensor to be: [3, 125] but got: [3, 1]. But indeed it works with 3x3 and 3x1.

Comment: The batch dimension should always go first (125x3x3 etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The batch dimension should always go first (125x3x3 etc.).

```bash
import torch

T = torch.zeros(125,3,1)
R = torch.zeros(125,3,3)

out = torch.matmul(R,T)
print(out.size())
```

Output:

```bash
torch.Size([125 3, 1])
```

To fill this new tensor you can do as with the 3x3 or the 3x1 using `:` :

```bash
T[:,0] = i
R[:,0,0] = datas_125_1
```